# Undo Database Restore in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, recovery

I accidentally restored a SQL Server 2008 database with a wrong backup. Is there any way to undo this and restore to previous version?

Comment: belongs on serverfault?

Comment: the db was not scheduled to take backups. is there any remote chance?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I feel for you but you're only recourse is to restore off the latest backup.

Comment: Dude whatever your boss tells you: This happened to all of us!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. The only solution is to do another restore with the proper backup file(s).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can restore from the *correct* backup, no.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote at: https://serverfault.com/questions/129290/undo-database-restore-in-sql-server-2008/129291#129291

No. You've replaced what's there with your restore. You would have to treat this the same as someone dropping your database - go to the most recent full database backup you have and then restore all subsequent log backups.

Sorry... you probably have that sick feeling right now. I feel bad for you.